# Sql statement sum total and qty in different table using?

Tags: mysql, sql

let say i have table named sell as parent and items as child

```
sell table
- id
- date
- total

items table
- id
- sell_id
- product_id
- qty
- price
```

I use simple schema to save selling product at my store.  i want to create report each day that can display `sum of total from sells table` and `sum of qty from items table`

my expected result something like this

```
 date | sum total | sum qty
  01        300        4
  02        4300      32
```

i tried with my sql statement like bellow

```
SELECT min(date) as `date`
     , sum(sell.total) AS `sum total`
     , sum(item.qty) AS `sum qty` 
  FROM `sell` 
  join `item`  
    ON sell.id = item.sell_id 
 WHERE month(date)='10'
 GROUP 
    BY date(sell.date) 
 ORDER 
    BY date(sell.date)
```

after sql fired i got result that fields date and qty return correct value, but total wasn't correct.

how to fixing my query to get all field with correct value?

Comment: Please provide sample data.  It is not clear  how the tables are related to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want:

```
select date, sum(total), sum(qty)
from ((select date, total, null as qty
       from sales
      ) union all
      (select s.date, null, i.qty
       from items i inner join
            sales s
            on i.sale_id = s.id
      )
     ) si
group by date
```

Comment: thanks, I got your point, i will try and come back after got result.

Comment: you missed inner join between i and sales on last select statement. i've edited and mark your answer